# node sharing in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

Is it possible that separate MapReduce jobs (their map/reduce tasks) submitted by different instances of Hadoop in the same shared cluster share available map/reduce slots in one node and run in parallel? 
If so, how frequent that scenario is?

Comment: Do you mean a datanode having 2 versions of hadoop installed?

Comment: well, in general several tasks of different jobs, can they run in parallel on the same node?

Comment: Yes, in Newer version of hadoop (YARN) every node has slots for executing map/reduce tasks. Until the node has free slots it can execute task of any job.

Comment: I see. Thanks! How about the old (pre-Yarn) versions?

Comment: in previous versions there are fixed no of mapper and reducer slots. If mapper slots are full it can't use available reducer slots. In Yarn it just has slots instead of mapper and reducer.